# How defining a const char* variable indirectly causes core dumping?

Tags: c

I've run this:

```
int main(){
    //const char* variable="Hello, World!";//random string
    for(char i=0;i<10;i++){//random limit
        char* arr;
        arr[0]=42;//random number
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It hasn't dumped core. But when I've uncommented the commented line and run it again, it produced this error-message:

```
/usr/bin/timeout: the monitored command dumped core
sh: line 1: 14403 Segmentation fault      /usr/bin/timeout 10s main
```

I was using https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php.

Why is this happening and what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: The string literal has absolutely *nothing* to do with what is wrong with this code. The code within the for-lop body is rife with *undefined behavior*. You're dereferencing an indeterminate pointer .

Comment: `char* arr; arr[0];`. What do you think should happen?

Comment: The definition does not cause any core dump. Accessing invalid memory does.

Comment: You forgot to allocate memory for `arr` before attempting to write to it.  That's an example of undefined behavior.  Any change to the program can cause the behavior to change.  That's why you can't have *any* bugs like that in your code.  All the other declaration does is change your memory layout.  It has nothing to do with the bug, but it can affect how the bug manifests itself.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour is causing the core dump, and Undefined Behaviour is causing the lack of core dump. To prevent it, don't write Undefined Behaviour in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr[0]=42;
```

is the same as

```
*(arr + 0)=42;
```

and also

```
*arr=42;
```

So you are putting the value 42 into the object that `arr` points to. However, you do:

```
char* arr;
```

so `arr` is uninitialized and it may point "anywhere" including illegal addresses that will cause a crash. It can also happen that it points to some legal address in which case the program will appear to work. So some times it crashes, other times it seem to work. That's in general called "undefined behavior". You can't know what such code will do...

To prevent this situation, you need to initialize `arr` to point to a valid object.

For instance:

```
char* arr = malloc(sizeof *arr);
```

Comment: That's indeed a problem with their code, but I think they meant why uncommenting the line that's commented would produce the error

Comment: @DuarteArribas Which is covered by: "It can also happen that it points to some legal address...." but I added a few extra words to make it more clear

Comment: I understand that but I don't know why the same isn't happening without existence of the "variable". In the real code I already have more than just variable "arr".

Comment: @markoj That's what "undefined behavior" is all about. Anything may happen and it is impossible to explain why something specific did happen. In your case the "extra" variable made it crash but it could just as well have been the other way around. It can't be explained... The cure: Write code with well defined behavior

Comment: The project I was working on was using pointers to input arrays into function. That input is actually where the output is stored. I knew that arrays are represented like that, so I haven't thought about allocating memory. Do you think this question isn't helpful to anyone and that I should delete it?

Comment: @markoj nah - don't delete it. Maybe someone pass by and find it helpful

Comment: I thought so. Okay.

Answer (score 0):

What the initialised pointer `arr` points to is undefined and non-deterministic.   Anything can happen including both apparently nothing or a core-dump.  Modifying the code simply changes what `arr` happens to point to.

In my test at https://onlinegdb.com/Q1k0Fd5oB it simply ran to completion in both cases (in both cases `arr == 0`).  That's the thing about undefined behaviour.  It is also worth noting that this code is also trivially optimised to a no-op (https://godbolt.org/z/7dTvrGaEf) in which case it would not core-dump.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent example of undefined behaviour.

If you corrupt even a single byte of memory (as you do here by writing into an unallocated array), you are likely to get away with it for a while (i.e. nothing will *seem* to happen), until a totally unrelated change in your code makes your application behave in all sorts of funny ways.

Consider yourself lucky: the crash is systematic and the modification that causes it is very close to the source of the bug. In real life, this corruption could cause an erratic behaviour, your program crashing out of the blue once per hour or per day, spouting the occasional corrupted data, etc.

And the cause of these malfunctions could be located in an entirely different part of the code, written weeks or months ago. That's right, the bug could lay dormant for months until some totally unrelated code change turns it into an app killer. Picture yourself sifting through a few months of code production to locate the source of the problem.

C and C++ are particularly unforgiving languages, leaving the programmer in charge of every single byte of allocated memory. Corrupting memory is extremely easy, and one single byte written where it shouldn't is enough to spell the doom of an entire application.

Moral of the story: sloppy programming is not an option in C/C++. If you don't learn to test your code extensively and adopt some basic [defensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) and [offensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offensive_programming) programming techniques early on, you (and your coworkers) are in for a world of pain.